# Loadout that allows for better armor and concealment value of 3

Tags: payday-2

What equipment loadout will allow for the best possible armor while maintaining a concealment rating of 3 for the character?

I do have the ghost perk that improves concealment by 5, which helps with this scenario.

Comment: What scenario are you referring to?

Comment: The game has changed since this was posted and the answers may no longer be accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CAR-4** has the best concealment of **31** out of all primary weapons when fully modified:

- Base Value of 20
- Short Barrel +2
- Competition Foregrip +2
- Straight Grip +2
- Vintage Mag. +2
- Folding Stock +3

Some additional mods can be added without affecting concealment.

---

**Swedish K** has the best concealment of **33** out of all secondary weapons when fully modified:

- Base Value of 24
- Grease Barrel +3
- Folded Stock +6

Again, some additional mods can be added without affecting concealment.

---

**Ghost Tier 4 Bonus** for unlocking any perk from the 4th tier. +5 concealment.

---

With this setup, you should be able to wear the **Heavy Ballistic Vest**, while still being at 3 detection risk. (I'm unable to verify as I'm missing 2 of the required mods for CAR-4, but I'm close enough to be sure.)

Do note that while heavier armour makes you more resistant against bullets, it also slows you down, and speed is important in stealth.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asked about the "best possible armor" the following analysis should be relevant:
http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2851x6/quick_analysis_of_armor_vs_dodge_mobility_and/

It discusses the trade-offs between dodge and armor value, and (depending on the heist selected) mobility.  With Ghost dodge bonuses (which most players will have from taking Fast Hands, and you certainly do with the higher-tier +5 concealment bonus), the best armor may very well be Ballistic Vest with concealmeant 23.  That has the further benefit of "freeing up" enough concealment to take one of the optimal weapon loadouts based on damage thresholds (link mentioned in another answer).

Ballistic Vest (23) + Ghost tier bonus (5) + Swedish K max conceal above (33) allows you to select a primary weapon with 28 concealment and still achieve detection risk 3 if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I've not fact-checked any of this, but this is based on my experience of playing regularly for the past 10 months (Infamy 1 - 95)

Is it really necessary  for you to have a concealment rating of 3?

Your concealment rating only affects the starting point of detection, so unless you frequently let the detection bar get almost full, you are slightly wasting your potential. If it is likely that it is going loud, keeping your concealment below 25 will probably not change much. How often has a mission gone loud because a guard/civ "almost didn't completely detect you, and an extra half a second would have changed everything"?

For example; doing easier missions like Bank Heist (branch), you can get away with much higher concealment ratings as typically a guard should only start spotting you when you are intending to kill him (on the roof or outside for example).

If you are struggling to stay alive after a mission goes loud, you could consider taking lower threat weapons. As far as I've noticed, cops you are shooting at are more likely to dive/stay in cover when you use a high threat weapon, but other cops (the ones you are not shooting at) are more likely to shoot at you too. Using silenced weapons against you means they will ignore you more and so you will soak up less damage (and instead let a team member with better armour/the AI take it instead).

My 3-concealment loadout:
MP5 with

- Bare Essentials Stock
- Silenced barrel
- See more sight (as this is my main weapon)

Commando 552 with the 2/3 concealment improving modes

- Heat treated body (upper receiver_
- Different grip (not sure on this)
- Stock?

As of last night, I've also introduced the new raven shotgun as a 3-concealment primary (with short barrel, maybe silencer)

Answer (score 0):

[Compilation of Optimal Weapon Loadouts](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=251751235)

ctrl+f "Maximum Concealment"

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.